# Comparar elementos de un vector de vectores definido con una vector

Tags: array, c, login

Estoy queriendo hacer un Login, el cual pida un legajo y password, que se debe comparar contra un vectr que tengo guardado legajos, y otro que guarda la contraseña.
Muchas gracias

[image: Comparar elementos de un vector definido con un vector en memoria]

En formato texto:

```
// 20 contraseñas de longitud máxima 20
char pass[20][20] = {"pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "pass5"};

// 5 caracteres no imprimibles en un vector de tamaño 20
char cLegajo[20] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
char iLegajo[20];
char Password[20];

do {
    printf("Ingrese el Legajo: ");
    scanf("%s", &iLegajo);
    printf("Ingrese la contrase%ca: ", 164);
    scanf("%s", Password);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(iLegajo, cLegajo) == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(Password, pass) == 0)
        }
    }
} while (...);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: *Comparar elementos de un vector de vectores definido con una vector..* ¿A que te refieres con vector de vectores? ¿Cuál es el problema con ese código? ¿Qué resultado da en tiempo de ejecución? ¿Qué resultado esperas? Falta detalles en esta pregunta.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con legajo? La RAE dice [esto](https://dle.rae.es/legajo). Pero en tu sistema de _login_, ¿qué función cumple?

Answer (score 0):

veo que en el código estas comparando un valor con un vector(y no con sus elementos). Si queres comparar "iLegajo" y "Password" con cada uno de los elementos de los vectores seria algo así:

```
if (strcmp(iLegajo, cLegajo[i]) == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(Password, pass[i]) == 0)
        }
```